# Residue integration

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

> Evaluate\begin{align}
> \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x^2+4x+5} \, dx
> \end{align}

I set $f(z) = \frac{1}{z^2 + 4z + 5} = \frac{1}{(z-z_0)(z-\bar{z_o})}$, where $z_0 = -2+i$ and $\bar{z_0} = -2 - i$. The top half circle contains a singularity point at $-2+i$. Therefore,
\begin{align}
\text{Res}_{z=-2+2i} f(z) = \frac{1}{z-\bar{z_0}} \Bigg\vert_{z=-2+2i} = \frac{1}{2i}
\end{align}
So we have
\begin{align}
\int_C f(z)e^z \, dz = \int_{-R}^{R} \frac{1}{x^2+4x+5} e^{ix} \, dx + \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{1}{(Re^{i \theta})^2+4(Re^{i \theta})+5}e^{i(Re^{i \theta})} = 2\pi i \frac{1}{2i} e^{i(i)} = \frac{\pi}{e}
\end{align}
As $R \rightarrow \infty$, we get
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2+4x+5} e^{ix} \, dx + 0 = \frac{\pi}{e}
\end{align}
where the middle term is $0$ by Jordan's lemma.

However, the correct answer is $-\frac{\pi}{e} \sin(2)$. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to look at the residue of *the whole integrand*, that is, $f(z)e^{iz}$, not just $f(z)$.  For a simple pole at $-2+i$ the residue is
$$r=\left.\frac{e^{iz}}{2z+4}\right|_{z=-2+i}$$
which gives
$$r=\frac{e^{-1-2i}}{2i}=\frac{e^{-1}(\cos2-i\sin2)}{2i}\ ,$$
and you will end up (after some other calculations) taking the imaginary part, which is where the $\sin2$ comes from.

I have calculated the residue using the following.

**Theorem**.  Suppose that $p$ and $q$ are analytic at $z_0$ and $p(z_0)\ne0$ and $q(z_0)=0$ and $q'(z_0)\ne0$.  Then $p/q$ has a simple pole at $z_0$ with residue
$$\frac{p(z_0)}{q'(z_0)}\ .$$

Comment: Okay, so I see that critical error I made in not finding the residue of the whole integrand. However, I had been trying to get $\text{Res}_{z=-2+i} f(z) = \frac{e^{iz}}{2z+4}\Big\vert_{z=-2+i}$ but I am drawing a blank there. If I can ask further, how was this obtained?

Comment: You could use the method in your question (after correction) and you should get the same answer.  However there is a very nice easy way of finding residues at simple poles.  I have added a note to my answer.  By the way I'm fairly sure the integral should be $-(\pi/e)\sin2$, not $(\pi/e)\sin2$.

Comment: Oh yeah, I remember that theorem of $\frac{p(z_0)}{q'(z_0)}$ (just covered it in my class a couple sections ago). If I recall correctly, does this work only for simple poles (poles of order 1)? (Also, yes there was a negative in the correct answer; made a typo.)

Comment: There is a vaguely similar formula for higher order poles.  I can't remember the details, but even for order $2$ it is a good deal more complicated and I have never known anyone use it in practice ;-)